# Spyder doesn't store variables between runs

Tags: python, spyder

Recently upgraded to spyder 4.1.5, and since then variables are not saved in the variable explorer between runs, if I use F5. If a mark the code and use F9 instead it can access all the variables in the variable explorer.

I have the following settings:
Console: Execute in current console
Working directory settings: The current working directory

I have not selected the "Remove all variables before execution" setting.

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer in this article: https://www.programmersought.com/article/81834280485/

Go to Tools>Preferences>Run and tick in the box for "Run in consoles namespace instead of an empty one".